1980s sci-fi or fantasy book about a planet surrounded by toxic clouds, from which invaders periodically arrive
I can only remember the barest of details.
It was set in a different world: the humans lived in an Earth-like setting surrounded by opaque, toxic clouds. Invaders periodically came out of the clouds to wage war.
The humans wielded magic, but the invaders had technology—tanks, etc. (IIRC, they couldn't breath our air, so they needed to bring air tanks) I vaguely remember there being something about stone towers that related to the human magic, and something about using magic causing the humans to get taller.
Near the end it was revealed that (spoilers) it was an alien world and it was the humans who were, technically, the invaders. I think.

I assume it was in English. Was it a US or UK publication?

Are the clouds on the planet, or in space around it?

I'm in the US but I can't recall if it's a US or UK publication.
The clouds are on the planet, surrounding the human habitation. I'm fairly sure the human habitation is a single, large area, though I don't know if it's circular or irregular, or what (if anything) is holding back the clouds).
